# Integrating a branch in the middle of another branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-rebase

There is a project where versions are managed only with a master branch and tagging.

I have to make a hotfix for a specific release and integrate it in the master branch.

The problem: The master branch already contains other commits which I don't want to include in the hotfix.

`Current state:
             (TAG: v3.2.0)
                  |
... ---C1---C2---C3---C4---C5---C6   (master)
                  \
                   \---C7---C8       (fix_bug_branch)
                             |
                        (TAG: v3.2.1)`

`Desired state:
             (TAG: v3.2.0)
                  |
... ---C1---C2---C3---C7---C8---C4---C5---C6  (master)
                           |
                      (TAG: v3.2.1)`

Is it possible to rebase or merge a scenario like that? How?

Comment: Does the history have to be linear? If not, you can just continue and merge fix_bug_branch into master. Despite originally being tagged on a different branch, the merge will make it such that every tag is an ancestor of master again.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't published your tag yet, you can rebase fix_bug_branch to reorder the commits then `git tag -f v3.2.1 <newsha1>` to rewrite your tag.

Otherwise, you can rebase to transform your 1st schema into the 2nd, but you will have a C8'

Comment: How you rebase to leave C7', C8' before C4'---C5'---C6'? (rewriting commits is not a problem)

Comment: Not sure about the question but maybe the answer is with `git rebase -i` and reordering the lines